# Loading a .NET DLL in Interaction Python on Linux

Tags: python, .net, ipython

I have a Linux server running Interactive Python notebooks. I also have a .NET DLL containing functionality that I would like to use in my IPython notebooks.

**How can I load a .NET DLL in my IPython notebook?**

I have looked at [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/), but it appears to be linked to Windows, and I haven't been able to find an installation for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I know how to get Python to work wih .NET. First and least known to me is IronPython. It is a Python interpreter written for .NET, so it naturally is able to interact with .NET code and respective DLLs.
The second way I know of is Python for .NET you already mentioned. I am using it a lot but I never tried the PyPi install which can be found under the name pythonnet (maybe this is already a solution to you).
However the sources of Python for .Net contain VisualStudio solutions which will compile for Mono. So you should be able to build the needed CLR for yourself. Usage examples can be found on the IronPython website or in the free available book [IronPython in Action - Dark Corners of IronPython](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dark-corners.shtml).

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't think IronPython will help me here. You say you are using Python for .NET a lot - do you know a procedure for getting Python for .NET to run on linux?

Comment: @lejon I am sorry but I am bound to Windows. However the procedure concerning Python should be the same. Once compiled put the clr.pyd somewhere into the PYTHONPATH. Then you should be able to do a '''import clr'''